# How can I see the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2008 while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This is probably a really easy question, but I've spent too much time looking for the answer, so I'm putting my question here:

Whenever I run an app in Visual Studio 2008, my solution explorer disappears... any suggestions as to how I can find it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While in debug mode, go to the "View" menu and click "Solution Explorer". Or use Ctrl+W, S

Answer (score 1):

When you are in Debug mode, you can always enable every part of the shell by going to `View` > `Solution Explorer` for example.
Remember that the layout of your shell changes between development mode and debug mode. You can save these changes if you want to (eg: when you reinstall Visual Studio) by using the `Import/Export Settings` in the `Tools` menu.